# How to know reputation question/answerwise separately ?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, questions, answers

I have asked some question and also answered some questions on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). How can I know how much reputation questionwise and answerwise separately ?

Is there any way to check this ?

It will be good if we have easy access to this. For example a tooltip will be helpful on user profile page something like this:

[image: Tooltips]

Comment: see the [rep tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/149206/naveed?tab=reputation) in profile.

Comment: @Lucifer: It shows both questions and answers reputation for specific time period. I want to know total reputation of my answers only.

Comment: Right now there is no way to know. Personally I don't think the benefit is worth the trouble of developing such a thing. What you need it for?

Comment: @Sha Dow Wiz Ard: Personally I think it is good to know for me. I can see No. of up-votes on my no-wiki answers(not questions) with each tag     on my profile. I also want to know total No. of reputation got from my non-wiki answers.

Comment: OK fair enough, you proposed this now as feature request so let's see what the community and developers will do. :)