# Design Vision Updates to the User Card

Tags: discussion, design, user-card

### Background

As part of our ongoing efforts to improve the design of the platform, which so far has included colors ([original post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386102/accessibility-update-colors) and [follow-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390761/colors-update-a-more-detailed-look)) and border-radius adjustments, we're now focusing on refining individual components to align with this [fresh design direction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392048/our-design-vision-for-stack-overflow-and-the-stack-exchange-network) while also enhancing usability. One of these components is the User Card, which is prominently used across the site.

The current User Card comes in three different variants, each displaying varying metadata and sizes based on their usage. The metadata can include elements like:

- Name (e.g. Lauren Ipsum)
- Role (e.g. Mod, Staff, Admin)
- Reputation
- Badges (gold, silver, bronze)
- Endorsements (e.g. "Recognized by [Collective]" within Collectives on Stack Overflow, "SME in [tag]" on Stack Overflow for Teams, and "Member of [Community]" on Stack Overflow for Teams
- Highlighted status (i.e. when a user is the author of a question, answer, or post)
- Tags (e.g. [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript), [svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svelte))
- Location (e.g. NY, NY)
- Date/time of post, answer, etc. (e.g. 2 hours ago)

[image: Three variants of the user card]

*Examples of the base variant with endorsement and the highlighted status, the full variant, and the minimal variant (note that across the site there are some deviations from these patterns).*

### Our request for you

As prolific users of this site, you know best what information is most pertinent when performing different tasks. We're keen to receive your feedback on the current User Card, and we've outlined a few questions to guide your input:

- Which aspects of the User Card are working well? Which could use improvement?
- What do you think about the [Expanded User Card](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/expanded-user-card)? Do you find it useful?
- When you consider the User Card in the context of these use cases, which metadata would you find most helpful to see?

  - The question asker’s user card on their question
  - A question editor’s user card on a question they have edited
  - The question asker’s user card on a search result or question list item
  - The user card attached to a comment
  - The question answerer’s user card on their answer
  - If you’re also familiar with Stack Overflow for Teams, you can also consider these use cases:

    - For You
    - Collections
    - Dashboard

### Next steps

We are eager to gather feedback on these User Card changes and iterate on concepts. Once we've made progress, we'll return to you for another round of feedback in hopes of finding the best possible solution. Other feedback related to the User Card that does not fall under the previous questions is also welcome!

Comment: Love this feedback request format, thank you.

Comment: Is staff label being changed to admin label?

Comment: I'd assume "admin" is a thing for teams and staff stays staff

Comment: @KevinB: Yep, "Admin" is a label from Teams – I don't think there are any plans to bring it to the public sites.

Comment: If the user is suspended, how is it going to be presented?

Comment: @VictorStafusa-BozoNaCadeia: Presumably, it would look the same way it does now – the user's rep is set to 1 while they're suspended. We generally don't draw attention to suspensions aside from a notice at the top of the user's profile itself.

Comment: @V2Blast if it wasn't mainly something useful for mods, I see some value in being able to tell at a glance if a 1 rep user is new, or suspended, especially if its a same name sock. Maybe something subtle like a red border over the usercard...

Comment: @V2Blast A user having 1 rep and no badges being the author of a massively upvoted question or answer does exactly the opposite: It draws a lot of attention!

Comment: I love that y'all are asking for feedback like this! It's awesome!

Answer (score 25):

Just thinking out loud and trying to draw on some older memories, the goals I had when looking at a user card were:

- To determine **who they are** (information about their username and avatar was plenty)
- To determine **if they are knowledgeable** (to be fair, rep and badges are a poor proxy for actual knowledge, but they're the only proxy we have)
- To determine **if they had any specific authority on the site** (the diamond for moderators was plenty, and while [I wish we could have symbols for staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367925/175248) just to declutter the thing, the staff label has to come along here as well)

Everything else is noise to me:

- Any indication that the poster is a new user is immaterial to my answering of their question or evaluating of their answer
- Any indication that the poster is recognized by a collective is not really boosting the "knowledgeable" aspect, it just means that some group of people in some tag that I happen to be posting to happen to think that they're pretty cool
- Their location (I'm *not* going to run into these people IRL, and even if I did, I sure as heck wouldn't be talking Stack Overflow to them)
- Their top tags (this isn't a social media platform, and there's no tooling that exists - nor should - to get someone to answer your question based on what you've tagged it as)

In short:  I just need enough information to reasonably identify them and see if they know what they're on about.  I said it before that rep/badges are a poor proxy for knowledge, but there is still some kind of assurance on getting an answer from someone with 10k+ rep than someone with 200 rep.  And of course, this perspective can vary by network site.

Comment: The staff and mod badges are on the account itself tho. How 'useful' is having them on the expanding usercard?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: It at least maintains consistency.  If you're a mod on this site it should be visible everywhere your profile data exists.  This is the authority piece I speak to, and being able to hit to the crux of that.  Before the staff label ever existed, we had to have a convention in which staff would self-identify both in their response and in their profile, which wasn't ideal.  I see the expanding card similarly; if you're a mod, you're just *branded* with it kinda everywhere.

Comment: i wouldn't be against mod labels being hidden in some cases and shown in others. Hide it on answers/questions, show it on comments. Show it in the expanded card.

Comment: Really only makes sense to show them everywhere on meta

Comment: As far as I'm aware, we made a very intentional decision to show the staff label on all meta sites but not on main sites, so that should already be the case. Moderators need a diamond on both since they may be acting specifically to moderate content on both main and meta sites - and this includes staff who are mods. For staff who aren't mods, we want them to be able to participate more normally since their status as staff should generally be unrelated to any posts they may create.

Comment: @Catija:  I dunno if that makes sense to me.  Like, I *get* it, staff only really matters on Meta, but that smells more to me like something in either the question or answer indicating that you're staff (analogous to how Reddit does it) makes more sense to me.  This way the user card can be reserved to only explicitly identify people who have some kind of authority relevant to the Q&A process.

Comment: We've had discussions on MSE in the past about how we indicate **posts** that are "official" answers rather than posts that happen to be from staff members. Right now, all of our indicators reference someone's current status so both in cases where someone who was active on meta becomes staff later or a staff member moves on, we have issues in retaining that "official" status. But I'm not sure fixing this should relate to the user card since I'd rather have it at the top of a post than the bottom.

Comment: @M-- I appreciate you're pinging me since I'm commenting here. While I love to participate in these conversations and add context where I can, I'm not directly involved in this project so I don't really have any sway in prioritizing the decisions here :D That said, I think we do want to be thoughtful about how we're designing Collectives features so my support likely isn't needed anyway.

Comment: @Catija:  The only reason why I'd call it out as a part of the user card is because it's a factor in the user card today.  A niche factor, but a factor nonetheless.  It'd be best to get these components to be consistent across the board, as sometimes, paying down one piece of tech debt results in uncovering another piece of tech debt.

Comment: That's understandable - I think I'd prefer to see this as something similar to the Collectives indicators on posts that are marked as recommended by the collective admins... That said, adding anything like that leaves me very afraid of how long it will take to add it to historical posts made by people on behalf of the company. :/

Comment: I disagree that collective recognition and tags are just noise - they're still a proxy for whether the user is knowlegdeable or not. However, I think the collective thing is too prominent, it should be not more of a signal than the badge counts. What would be ideal (but probably harder to implement) if the user card could show something about the knowledge specifically in the question tags, e.g. bronze/silver/gold badges and answer score.

Answer (score 19):

You're updating the user card? Great! The user cards have never worked right.

```html
<!-- My user card from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389576/308065,
     as of 2023-08-10. -->
            <div class="post-signature flex--item fl0">
                <div class="user-info user-hover">
    <div class="user-action-time">
        answered <span title="2023-05-30 17:12:37Z" class="relativetime">May 30 at 17:12</span>
    </div>
    <div class="user-gravatar32">
        <a href="/users/308065/wizzwizz4"><div class="gravatar-wrapper-32"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdOvO.png?s=64&amp;g=1" alt="wizzwizz4's user avatar" class="bar-sm" width="32" height="32"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="user-details" itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <a href="/users/308065/wizzwizz4">wizzwizz4</a><span class="d-none" itemprop="name">wizzwizz4</span>
        <div class="-flair">
            <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score 13,481" dir="ltr">13.5k</span><span title="5 gold badges" aria-hidden="true"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">5</span></span><span class="v-visible-sr">5 gold badges</span><span title="29 silver badges" aria-hidden="true"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">29</span></span><span class="v-visible-sr">29 silver badges</span><span title="43 bronze badges" aria-hidden="true"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">43</span></span><span class="v-visible-sr">43 bronze badges</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


            </div>
```

There are *so* many things wrong with this. Copy-pasting as plain text is a *reasonable* proxy for what assistive tech will see:

> answered May 30 at 17:12
> wizzwizz4's user avatar
> wizzwizz4wizzwizz4
> 13.5k55 gold badges2929 silver badges4343 bronze badges

There's a hack with `aria-hidden="true"` and `class="v-visible-sr"` which makes it *slightly* better in screen readers (but only if via a fancy modern web browser) – but there's still [the superfluous and *verbose* alt text on the profile pictures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379431/308065).

I'd expect it to read more like this:

> answered May 30 at 17:12
> by wizzwizz4
> 13.5k reputation
> badges: 5 gold, 29 silver, 43 bronze

Or *maybe* (if you can get this by describing things semantically, [without hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43496525/5223757)):

> answered May 30 at 17:12
> by wizzwizz4, link
> 13 point 5 thousand reputation
> badges: 5 gold, 29 silver, 43 bronze

There are hidden elements that just bloat up the page, and don't *quite* do Microdata right. (RDFa is strictly superior to Microdata, but that's neither here nor there.) If you find yourself writing `class="d-none" itemprop=`: stop, take a step back, and double-check whether that information is already in the document.

Much of this stuff is probably under the purview of "developers" at the moment. Speaking as a developer: most developers are *really bad* at this kind of thing. (Notice how I haven't given any implementation suggestions? My attempts are [hot garbage](https://wizzwizz4.codeberg.page/sxwand/@main/testing/mock2/q1234.html).) A design team has a different perspective: one I think is better suited for these kinds of things.

---

Note well: I'm not suggesting any visual or layout changes. The usercards have to satisfy a *lot* of competing requirements, many of which are obscure:

- they need to work right when the reputation line is absent, as on MathOverflow;
- they need to look similar-ish to the userflair images:
  [image: profile for wizzwizz4 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]
  (speaking of which, the flair's default alt text is inappropriate; and it'd be nice to have an accessibly-marked-up SVG version – but this is out of scope);
- they need to handle incredibly long, incredibly large usernames (like AAAA᭛ဪ꧄﷽⸻) gracefully;
- they need to work in Zoom Text Only mode. (The current behaviour is correct.)
- they need to handle RTL usernames, and contain directional overrides. (The current behaviour is correct; though comments don't ‮contain‬ directional overrides properly.)
- they *should* handle top-to-bottom usernames, if possible: even though SE has no software support for it, machine translation is a thing. (There are some HTML examples [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_Mongolian_alphabet).) The current usercard doesn't do this.
- they need Jon Skeet support.
- they *should*, if at all possible, maintain the traditional class names. `.-flair` (and probably others) basically hasn't changed since the start of the site, and is assuredly in use by userscripts and userstyles.
- they need keyboard navigability. Currently, it's annoying (the timing of pressing Tab affects where you navigate) but otherwise fully-functional.

If the changes we get maintain (or add!) this functionality, I'll be happy (pretty much) regardless of what we end up with.

Comment: Probable duplicate of: [User avatars are noisy in screen readers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379431/323179). As I point out in the comments, there should not be two adjacent links to the same place but one link that encompasses both parts.  Pressing tab an extra time is annoying, more so if you're on a screen reader and have to hear it again.

Comment: @Laurel Yeah, I linked that in the answer (which covers a couple of other things, too). Though, under the current design, the image being tabbable separately is how the overlay thing is accessed.

Comment: Can you help me understand what the snippet is intended to show? Do you think maybe you could add a bit of a preamble to explain the focus of your answer? It seems like you're talking about screen readers specifically but the general statement that they've never worked doesn't help me contextualize your answer :D Even if you just mean to say "they've never worked right with screen readers".

Comment: I think its expected to show how a user card looks to a screenreader *now*, without using a screen reader

Comment: @Catija I would assume the code in the snippet was just copied from the web inspector, meaning, it's the HTML your server sent to their browser. You can open the web inspector, use the "element picker", hover over the current user cards on your website, and click with the mouse. That should take you to the part of the HTML that specifies the user cards.

Comment: @Catija Yes, can confirm. I just did what I described, and the HTML in the snippet is indeed what your servers send to our browsers. Stack Exchanges's final (rendered/generated) HTML makes absolutely no sense, an issue which has been pointed out over and over again.

Comment: @Catija In short, if you are to fix this issue, you would probably have to overhaul your entire system. Good luck.

Comment: @Catija [Here's why, btw](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks).

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype Stacks has most of the problems of Bootstrap, but only those. It is not to my tastes, but it does not _preclude_ accessible web development. (That said, an accessible website would have places that aren't _idiomatic_ Stacks.) Most of the problems with the site predate Stacks: the only issue Stacks has added is increased page weight.

Comment: @Catija I've added an informative comment to the snippet. Like many websites, Stack Exchange uses CSS to paper over the fact that its HTML makes almost no sense. (It could be worse: a large chunk of the web uses _JavaScript_ for this purpose, whereas SE sites are still readable via `echo -en "GET /q/42 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: stackoverflow.com\r\nUser-Agent: mSE /posts/comments/1311745\r\n\r\n" | ncat --ssl stackoverflow.com 443`.)

Answer (score 12):

> If you’re also familiar with Stack Overflow for Teams, you can also consider these use cases

Amusingly - [something Catija pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368386/add-a-role-line-in-teams-usercards-for-members-to-note-their-position-or-job-t). In a larger organisation, it’s very hard to remember who is who. Having the title field would help here. In the context of the moderator team, we can put what sites we're moderator of there, so it’s easy to check what role someone has in the organisation without going into their profile.

Comment: <3 This has long been one of my favorite Teams-related requests and I was just opining in the TL a week or so ago about how I couldn't easily identify who belonged to which site now that the network site list isn't on Teams profile pages.

Answer (score 11):

**[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Make the endorsement text/badge optional.**

---

Now that you are updating the user cards, I think it's a good time for me to bring up this feature request from Meta Stack Overflow: [Remove "Recognized by XYZ Collective" text from the Recognized Member (RM)'s flair](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424338/remove-recognized-by-xyz-collective-text-from-the-recognized-member-rms-fla)

Issues with the endorsement feature for Collectives are laid out in that post in details, but in short, they cause a bias towards RMs' answers that is not desired at all times.

I really liked the idea of making them optional at the time of posting.

Answer (score 10):

Generally I don't use user-cards as a source of information outside of who is posting, I don't care what badges they have, if they've answered enough dupes to be in the top 3 of a collective, if they've been "recognized", or if they're a new contributor (isn't the new contributor indicator part of the user card?)

Historically this has been a place used to show off the user's achievements to aid in the gamification process, a form of "Look at all the badges/rep this other user has, don't you want that too?!!", however, for the same reason, it also draws users to change the way they interact with content based on what is in the user-card, both positively and negatively.

> Which aspects of the User Card are working well? Which could use improvement?

I'd like to see user avatars on all variants, that's often the most obvious thing to look at to see if it's a user you've seen before.

> What do you think about the Expanded User Card? Do you find it useful?

Yes, I think the expanded user card is useful as a way of allowing users who *want* to see this information to do so without having all of this information directly visible in a place where it can impact voting. I'd like to see recent additions moved to here as well.

> When you consider the User Card in the context of these use cases, which metadata would you find most helpful to see?

> The question asker's user card on their question

Whether or not the user has been recently active, *relevant* gold/silver badges

> A question editor's user card on a question they have edited

None.

> The question asker's user card on a search result or question list item

None.

> The user card attached to a comment

None.

> The question answerer's user card on their answer

Whether or not the user has been recently active, *relevant* gold/silver badges

Comment: When you say *"relevant gold/silver badges"* I assume you mean things like tag badges actually showing as tag badges, and not a count of badges associated with the that specific functionality of the site (like, a count of good answer badges)

Comment: Right, kinda like how when displaying dupe close users the gold badge that allowed it to be binding is displayed.

Comment: Awesome, would be totally on board with that idea

Answer (score 9):

> What do you think about the Expanded User Card? Do you find it useful?

I don't ever really use it, but it seems potentially useful, and if there is a business or community need to add more information to the card, the Expanded User Card might be a better place for that information. It also has the potential to add information or functionality for moderators (quick list of ideas that might fit: access to Mod/"Moderator Actions" window from profile, link to chat profile, link to Dashboard, number of flags/annotations). I think of it more like a "mini profile" than an expanded user card, and if it made it easier to access profile functionality I think I'd use it more.

It's quirky, though:

1. Doesn't make much sense on mobile.
2. [Unclear how to even trigger it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392119/401068) - who would think that hovering over the *avatar* has some functionality to it? It's too long of a hover to easily trigger accidentally...
3. For new users, it's disabled (*edit: maybe I'm misremembering this, is it only when users don't have a profile that it doesn't appear? in that case I don't really understand why it doesn't just expand for everyone...even if there's no content, at least let us know our mouseover worked!*), which helps keep spammy profiles more hidden, but there's no UI or design hint to this that I perceive. If I was trying to trigger the expanded card for a new user, it feels like I'm doing something wrong rather than encountering intended behavior.

Comment: "Doesn't make much sense on mobile." Actually, it can be triggered with a long tap (iOS). And it is enabled for low rep users — take a look at user ChatGPT Stan elsewhere on this page.  Agree that it's not obvious that it exists (on any platform) though.

Comment: @Laurel Yeah that was my mistake (see the edit I already made), it's based on profile length instead apparently, but it doesn't communicate this at all. On my browser on android, sometimes it doesn't work at all, and sometimes I see the expanded card *after* I dismiss the long tap popup menu that would let me manipulate the image or link underneath.

Answer (score 9):

Are there any plans for user card updates for community wiki posts?

[image]

I always felt that this line wrap happening after % is somewhat inorganic.

Also, [flairs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/flair) are extremely dated low resolution pictures. Will updates for them be a part of this redesigning effort? Seems to be close enough to solve these issues at the same time.

[image: profile for markalex at Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites]

Comment: related prior flair requests: [Have a higher-resolution flair for printing](/q/130607/997587), [Flair images low resolution on retina displays](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262704/11107541), [SVG Flairs (In Addition To PNG Flairs)?](/q/65759/997587), [Optimise Stack Exchange user flair for Retina displays](/q/131045/997587)

Comment: I agree that these tend to be very confusing. In addition to the odd alignment, while we show the username of the user responsible for the highest percentage of the content, that entire link is to the revision history, which is already available immediately beside the user card (if the post has been edited) but does not link to the user's profile. As such, the only way to actually get to the profile of that user, one has to go to the edit history first and then find an edit by them to get the link to their profile.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if there's an existing feature-request post about this, and this idea came from someone I can't remember (Oleg?), but I think it's an idea worth considering seriously:

In Q&A pages, instead of showing the user's total reputation, show the sum of the reputation they have in other posts with overlapping tags. Reputation is often used by readers as a proxy for measuring subject-matter-expertise, so I think it makes sense to not show reputation in a Q&A that is unrelated to the tags of that Q&A- at least on main sites. Meta sites can show total rep.

If space isn't a concern, it would even be useful to show the breakdown of rep for each tag. If space is a concern, one option could be to put that under the expanded user card.

I'm not sure if there are any technical performance blockers here. I know the user profile page does have a section on tag rep, so I assume that any caching done for that (if at all) can be reused.

---

I've always been interested in the possibility of getting question and answer rep show separately. In my mind, answer reputation is a stronger indicator of subject-matter-expertise than question rep. I'm not sure how much this has been discussed. I just searched and saw [How to know reputation question/answerwise separately ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136655/997587).

---

On the expanded user card, I wish it made it easier to reach out to someone in chat. At least linking to their chat profile (if they have one) would go a long way. It's *really really* hecking annoying to get to a user's chat profile.

I assume there'd be concerns about high-rep users getting annoyed by getting contacted by other users, but there's already a feature to ignore users in chat.

See also the fairly popular [Let's make it easier to get a room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288572/997587).

There's also the (sadly, declined) [Create comment-spawned chatrooms for the post, not for the users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98926/997587), but I digress...

Comment: This can be confusing. Maybe we can settle for showing the gold/silver badges in the overlapping tags? Kinda like what Kevin suggested in their answer.

Comment: As a more discrete (and I guess obscure) option, if space is at a premium, showing a ball to indicate a gold / silver / bronze badge in one of the question's tags instead of the rep could also work, the way it's already displayed next to the user name in tae close notice when a gold badge owner has closed a question as a duplicate. (I see @M-- posted a similar comment whilst I composed this, but I'm leaving it for the more detailed description.)

Comment: @tripleee There's something like this in the mod UI (the per-site leaderboard). It's obscure, but it has tooltips, and for me it works.

Answer (score 7):

### Show the one tag-related badge that is most relevant to that user's question.

This is a badge that

- Is one of the tags below the question.
- Is one of the user's tag badges that is the most specific,
- or otherwise: has the highest class (i.e. gold > silver > bronze)

To clarify *most specific badge*: many users have tag badges in a programming language, but if besides that, a user also has a tag badge in e.g. [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate), which occurs less often, then that badge is more relevant in questions that are tagged e.g. [java](/questions/tagged/java) [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate).

This will show at a glance that the answer is from someone who has gained some credibility in that specific tag. Besides votes, this helps later visitors to sort out the most helpful answers.

In my experience, tag badges are (far) more meaningful than reputation. (A tag badge in combination with relatively low rep even strongly indicates that we're dealing with a specialist).

The only thing is, it's probably a very expensive operation to find this badge :)

Comment: "_it's probably a very expensive operation to find this badge_" I kind of doubt that it's _very_ expensive.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I put very expensive things on my wish list - against better judgment.

Comment: I made a bold edit, please feel free to rollback or re-edit. It wasn't immediately clear to me at first glance.

Answer (score 6):

As a mod, the main thing I'd appreciate is for deleted users to still be linked to the deleted user profile. (For non-mods, that is a limited profile which just has things like the reason for deletion and a link to view the post's written by the user.)

Comment: I believe Catija's working with our Community Enablement product team to look into implementing something along these lines already :)

Comment: Yeah, we're doing a design investigation for how we would build this right now.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you again for getting feedback for these changes like this - I really hope this kind of feedback loop will become the norm and the feedback will be valuable and acted on.

The user card seems like a hard topic. Currently it does what it needs to do perfectly: It doesn't distract from the content and is hardly noticeable while still giving context about the user.

The expanded user card in particular can be a great thing to revamp here. At the moment it doesn't display much information other than the user's country and a bit of the profile description. But it also looks... old. I think it in particular could do with some context-dependent information or maybe even some personalization as someone has to hover or click for it and it wouldn't influence voting or how content is perceived as much.

I don't know where the view displaying the user's tags is in use (Teams?), but I believe adding context-dependent information like this would skew readers toward reading and voting on certain content based on the poster (which we don't want).

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, I believe that version of the usercard matches what's already shown on the "Users" page of a site (e.g. [here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users)). It looks like badge counts are only shown on the Teams version of the Users page – but otherwise, that info is already shown on the current version of the Users page on the public sites.

Answer (score 5):

> Which aspects of the User Card are working well? Which could use improvement?

I think that most users would like to see the nickname, the photo, the reputation and the badges. You could also add title and location, but I guess that most users will find this information to be excessive and polluting, but you might run a few experiments.

> What do you think about the Expanded User Card? Do you find it useful?

After roughly 14 years at Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites, I still don't know how to expand a user card. I don't think that I ever saw one, and if I did, it was a long time ago and I don't remember it anymore. I just tried to do this right now, and failed.

> When you consider the User Card in the context of these use cases, which metadata would you find most helpful to see?

Nickname, image, reputation, badge count and special powers (mod / staff / new user / nothing special).

[Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) is a site that shows job titles with users, like "CEO of XYZcorp Inc." or "Sr. tech lead at Foobar Services", etc. And I think it is awful. People here, would like end up using "Alien dog-feeder", "None of your business", "Master god of the multiverses", "Queen of Spades" and other trollish titles.

Location could be interesting in some cases, but I think that it is more likely to cause xenophobia than anything else.

However, those two could be useful for the expanded card.

Further, each question or answer should have the authors card, something about the last editor, and I also suggest something to tell who are all the editors without having to see all the edition history.

For comments, there should be some way to see the user card also, but it should be hidden by default to not pollute the screen.

Further, if the user is suspended, show the exact same user card as a normal user. Don't hide the reputation nor the badges as a user with no badge and only 1 rep in a 50-upvotes answer clearly draws attention when the intent of the suspension is to not draw too much attention.

Comment: "After roughly 14 years at StackOverflow and StackExchanges sites, I still don't know how to expand a user card." You hover over the ava. I wonder if expanding the hitbox to the name itself has value...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ok, you finally cleared up the mystery! Was too used with the idea that the site should only react to of either clicking or typing something or scrolling the screen, and nothing more than that.

Comment: FYI, [there's a Help Center page about the expanded user card functionality here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/expanded-user-card). (It was originally part of the [established user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege page, but then it was granted to everyone so the info was moved to the [create posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts) privilege page – but that didn't really make sense, so I ended up creating a new Help Center page for it instead.)

Comment: That said, I agree that there's currently no obvious indication that this functionality exists (if you don't already know about it), and it doesn't necessarily work intuitively (you have to hover over their profile image for a while, and hovering over any other part of the usercard doesn't work).

Comment: @V2Blast I have a vague recollection that before we expanded the feature to everyone, the high-rep users had a drop shadow on their avatar that (for me, anyway) led me to hovering to understand why some had the shadow and others didn't... and discovery of the user card. Still took me a while to figure out why only some people had them, though.

Comment: Ah, here it is - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390764/expanded-usercards-are-not-showing-drop-shadow/390765#390765

Comment: Yes, it is one of the many hidden features. The same with hovering over anything with a time (e.g., *"answered 3 hours ago"*). It will the show the absolute time, down to the second ("Z" is for [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), more or less). Example: ***"2023-08-09 20:48:32Z"***. For times on comments, it weirdly includes ***", License:  CC BY-SA 4.0"*** as well.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Note that, since that's the only place comment licenses are described, [license information for comments is entirely inaccessible to segments of the userbase](https://webaim.org/articles/gonewild/#title).

Answer (score 5):

If any more information is to be added to the user cards, perhaps it would be worth moving some of the current information around to prevent cramping.

- Maybe a background colour to indicate their role (mod, staff, etc), similar to new contributor or question asker.
- Move relevant icons to where the new contributor text is currently shown (without the actual text).

Rough example;

[image]

Comment: I didn't note it in the text, but added it in the image - most active networks (so, su, etc) could be included in the bottom bar

Comment: The icons at the bottom actually look pretty nice. Maybe also inset a diamond at the bottom if you're a mod on the relevant sites

Comment: We'll need for different, distinctive enough colours: OP, mod, staff, and presumably mod&staff = CM. And explain till <s> the rest of the days </s> next redesign, why somebody has this background, and somebody don't. Also, I'm not sure on this, but I feel like published design vision has an attempt to move on from excessive use of backgrounds: even what's left of HMP lost background.

Comment: [Should SE Staff have a Special Character in Their User Name?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246678/should-se-staff-have-a-special-character-in-their-user-name)

Answer (score 5):

> The user card attached to a comment

I am not sure exactly how you may plan to implement this without making it cluttered. But I would like to see a small user card upon hovering on the name of the user (with a bit of delay of course) instead of seeing just reputation.

Answer (score 3):

> Which aspects of the User Card are working well? Which could use improvement?

I think the user card for questions and answers is too cluttered. The essential information is the user name, the avatar, the original creation time, the last edit time. In certain contexts, knowing that someone is a moderator or staff is important. Everything else is not only extraneous, but there have been questions about if showing reputation and badges tends to result in even more up votes and/or acceptances because the person is seen as an expert. I would recommend moving more information to the Expanded User Card and going with an absolute minimum on posts, similar to how it is displayed on comments or the home page.

> What do you think about the [Expanded User Card](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/expanded-user-card)? Do you find it useful?

Could use some formatting, but yes. The content is useful, but some of that is based on how the profile is structured. For example, if you have a lot of external links or profiles, you're stuck putting them in the bio. That's more of a profile problem than an expanded user card problem, though, although giving more flexibility and power to the profile could help solve these expanded user card problems.

I'd also expand so a hover over the profile picture or the name brings it up.

> When you consider the User Card in the context of these use cases, which metadata would you find most helpful to see?

The bare minimum is the user name and date. Most information can be left to the expanded user card or profile. Also consider bringing the expanded user card to comments.

When it comes to the expanded user card, I would like to see relevant "credentials" more easily. For example, badges in a tag that is applied to the question. Or for editors, badges related to editing/curating content.

I'd strongly recommend doing some research into the display of reputation and badges. There have been some discussions in the past indicating that people with high reputation and badge counts get more attention than people who don't, even if that reputation or badges aren't from the subject matter of the question. Hiding this information in the primary views and leaving it to the detailed profile could level the playing field between people, although anyone with name recognition would still have that advantage.

Answer (score 1):

To keep in line with the vote on content and not the author, I'd go with the third version without the reputation: just name as a link to the user profile the same way it is done for the comments (without the staff/mod tags on normal sites, with them on meta sites as they probably need these tags to weight on).

All the info on the user card are distracting and bringing bias in my humble opinion, so I'd favor a username with profile link only, maybe still with the avatar if it doesn't clutter screen readers.

Comment: ... even get rid of the timestamp? =.=

Comment: @starball well, I guess the timestamp isn't part of the user card. I'm not sure about the timestamp (on what it brings), but surely it can help see if an answer is recent or could be outdated so I assume it would be better to keep it.

Answer (score -7):

Currently, very few possible values and user attributes are available in the public Q&A platform. What are the restrictions that we should be aware of to avoid going in favor of "creative" but unfeasible suggestions / requests?

##### Role

The available values are Staff, Mod and Bot. If more roles are coming soon, like "Admin". Could each of them have a unique color? What about the diamond used for mods? Could the other roles have a unique symbol?

##### Endorsements

Will endorsements be available elsewhere besides Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow for Teams?

##### Location

Is it possible to show a different attribute than the location?

##### Expanded User Card

<s>Will the expanded user card be available for low-reputation users?</s> I was using it wrongly, I'm sorry. Details [The expanded user card is not being displayed to me. What I'm missing? As of August 2023, are there system or privileges requirements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392214/1395520).

##### Chat

Is the scope of this post limited to user cards on the public Q&A platform and SOFT, or does it also include the chat platform?

Comment: *"Will the expanded user card be available for low-reputation users?"* - it has been for ~3 years

Comment: I can point you to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342575/684990 which is where the rep removal was confirmed. Also, here's a screenshot of it working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeRvp.png

Comment: @ChatGPTStan: [See this Help Center page on the expanded user card feature.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/expanded-user-card)